# Stable homotopy groups of $RP^{\infty}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Are the stable homotopy groups $\pi^s_i(\mathbb R P^{\infty})$ known for small $i$? In particular, I would be interested in the values for $i = 5,6$. A quick Internet search did not lead to anything.

Comment: This might contain the answer: http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5942

Comment: In addition to the calculation that Matthias Wendy points out, Mahowald's memoir "The metastable homotopy of $S^n$" does a lot of calculation with the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for stable homotopy groups of projective spaces (because this calculation connects to the EHP spectral sequence).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following paper contains a list of stable homotopy of projective spaces in dimensions $\leq 8$:

- A. Liulevicius. A theorem in homological algebra and stable homotopy projective spaces.  Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
  Vol. 109, No. 3 (Dec., 1963), pp. 540-552

[JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993859)

In particular, $\pi^s_5=0$ and $\pi^s_6=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Answer (score 8):

The middle column of table IV on page 82 of George W. Whitehead's "Recent Advances in homotopy theory" Regional Conference series in mathematics Number 5
lists the groups in dimensions up to 30 (including the 2 quoted by Matthias Wendt).