# Ring spectra structures on a certain spectral analogue of $\mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, higher-algebra, ring-spectra

We can characterise $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ as the corepresenting abelian groups of the functors
\begin{align*}
    \mathsf{Forget} &\colon \mathsf{Ab} \to \mathsf{Sets},\\
    \mathrm{Inv}    &\colon \mathsf{Ab} \to \mathsf{Sets}
\end{align*}
given by $(A,\cdot_A,1)\mapsto A$ and $A\mapsto\mathrm{Inv}(A)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\left\{a\in A\ \middle|\ a^2=1_A\right\}$.

[A similar approach](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404304) in the $\infty$-world gives the $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-groups $QS^0$ and $\Omega Q\mathbb{RP}^\infty$. Passing to spectra via the [equivalence between $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-groups and connective spectra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280980), we obtain the sphere spectrum $\mathbb{S}$ corresponding to $QS^0$ and a spectrum $E$ corresponding to $\Omega Q\mathbb{RP}^\infty$.

(One possible name for $E$ might be "$\mathbb{S}/2$" since it satisfies an analogous universal property to that of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, corepresenting "involutory objects". However, that notation already usually denotes the mod 2 Moore spectrum, so let's write $E$ for it instead.)

For comparison, their first $8$ homotopy groups are as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi_0(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z},\\
\pi_1(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_2(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_3(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/24,\\
\pi_4(\mathbb{S}) &\cong 0,\\
\pi_5(\mathbb{S}) &\cong 0,\\
\pi_6(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_7(\mathbb{S}) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/16\times\mathbb{Z}/3\times\mathbb{Z}/5,
\end{aligned}
\quad\quad
\begin{aligned}
\pi_0(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_1(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_2(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/8,\\
\pi_3(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_4(E) &\cong 0,\\
\pi_5(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_6(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/16\times\mathbb{Z}/2,\\
\pi_7(E) &\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2.
\end{aligned}
$$
(The ones for $E$ are taken from [Liulevicius](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993859?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents); see also [MO 230790](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230790).)

---

What (homotopy associative, homotopy commutative, $\mathbb{A}_k$-, $\mathbb{E}_k$-, or $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-) ring spectra structures, if any, are there on $E$?

Comment: S/2 doesn't have a unital multiplication. In general, S/p does have an A_{p-1}-structure, but not an A_p-structure.

Comment: "$\mathbb S / 2$" would standardly denote the mod 2 Moore spectrum, which is the same as $\Sigma^{\infty-1} \mathbb R \mathbb P^2$... but you've defined "$\mathbb S/2$" to be $\Omega Q (\mathbb R \mathbb P^\infty)$... first of all $Q(X)$ usually means $\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty X$, so what you've written is a space and not a spectrum, thought the (unstable) homotopy groups of $\Omega Q \mathbb R \mathbb P^\infty$ are the same as the (stable) homotopy groups of $\Sigma^{\infty-1} \mathbb R \mathbb P^\infty$. Still, that's a different spectrum from the mod 2 Moore spectrum. Could you clarify?

Comment: @TimCampion I was writing "$\mathbb{S}/2$" to mean the connective spectrum associated to the $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-group $\Omega Q\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ because it satisfies an analogous universal property to the one for $\mathbb{Z}/2$: while morphisms of monoids from $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ to a monoid $A$ are the same as invertible/involutory elements of $A$, symmetric monoidal functors from $QS^0$ and $\Omega Q\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ to $\mathcal{C}$ are the same as invertible/involutory objects of $\mathcal{C}$. I've edited the question to use a less confusing notation. Thanks, Tim!

Comment: @skd Sorry for the confusing notation! I didn't mean the mod 2 Moore spectrum

Comment: $(-)^\times$ is a pretty weird name for what seems to be the forgetful functor from abelian groups to sets...

Comment: @Achim I was also puzzled, but it is a good name for functor on rings corepresented by the group ring on Z. Given some of the other adjunctions floating around, perhaps that’s closer to what was intended?

Comment: @Achim and Eric It is a weird name! I did have in mind another related statement as Eric said (that $\mathbb{Z}$ corepresents the group of units functor $(-)^\times\colon\mathsf{CMon}\to\mathsf{Sets}$ from commutative monoids to sets).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no left-unital multiplications on E. If there were, then for any element $x$ in $\pi_n(E)$, we would have $x+x = 1 \cdot x + 1 \cdot x = (1+1) \cdot x = 0$ because all elements in $ \pi_0 E$ are 2-torsion. This is not satisfied by the homotopy groups in your table.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!